Detect a blog Post and get the view count with Intersection Observer on the Nuxt app
I want to count the post view on a page of my Nuxt app when user scroll to it .
I have a list of posts on a page and I am using Intersection Observer to count Post views. When a user scrolls to a Post up/down that post view count must be increased by 1. I am using Nuxt js here. Not sure whether my procedure is correct or not because it increases the number of counts by 10, as it's on the foreach loop and posts loaded 10 per page (Maybe taking the loop count).
I just want, if the user views (focus ) on a post scrolling up or down, just increase the post view count by 1 .
Here is what I did.
mounted() {
   this.postScroll();
}
.......


 methods () {
  
    const posts = document.querySelectorAll(".postBody"); // Sélectionner toutes les vidéos
    // currently fetching 10 posts per page as the setting is set to 10 
    
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => { 
       entries.forEach(entry => {
            entry.target.classList.toggle('visible', entry.isIntersecting)
            
            if(entry.isIntersecting && entry.target.classList.contains('visible')){
               // get post id from postBody  
               const postId = entry.target.getAttribute("id")
                
              //Here I am calling the server and there increased the count by current view +1
               try{
                  axios.post(`${this.$config.apiBaseURL}/api/posts/${postId}/view`)
                    .then(res => {
                        console.log(res)
                    })
                }catch(error){
                    console.log("An error occcured , Please try again later.")
                }
                observer.unobserve(entry.target);
            }
        })
        
    }, {threshold: 1});


    posts.forEach((post) => {
        observer.observe(post);

    });
}

I am not sure whether to attach a scroll or focus event or not.
But I think I am doing something wrong on the whole process When scrolling it increased the view count by 10, but If I scroll to a post on the page view count should be increased by 1.
In general If I scroll to a post, the view count should be counted by 1.

You probably need to add a debounce or some way or deduping the call so that you do not have 15 of them when you scroll. Also prefer using VueUse and its intersection observer composable rather than vanilla JS selectors.

Also are you trying to get some metrics here or have an infinite scroll?

Could even use this one to have a callback and increment the counter of post views (when you reach the bottom of it).

Just scroll if view the post , the get the count as 1  and I am not using composition API of vue

You can also use Options API with VueUse. Otherwise it is still feasible in the several ways I listed above.

I am checking with , if(entry.isIntersecting && entry.target.classList.contains('visible'), but it still gives me 10 values of a postId??

Maybe try to console log the entry that is triggering the event to see if it's the same one or some other ones. Not sure if looping this way is the way to go either. I would have put the observer inside of the loop rather.

entries.forEach(entry => { ....      for this loop its counting 10 instead 1 ? here 10 is number of entries total , maybe its count this
